# What are the differences between male and female speech in Russian?

Tags: узус, социолингвистика

Can someone shed some light on this?

The differences in *1st. p. sg. past tense* are obvious, but there should be some more discrepancies in male and female varieties of Russian than just preferences in swearing (like men are likely to swear more often and with a specific vocabulary).

There should be some more differences in *monologue speech* between the two genders.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give some clearer motivation for asking this? Using swearing as an instance of the difference in speech can be construed as impolite, whether or not you consider it to be so. One could just as well ask how men and women behave differently in other vulgar aspects of life, and I don't think such a topic would be appreciated.

Comment: @KCd, actually the difference in speech patterns or "conversational rituals" between men and women is an active area of research in socio-linguistics. And how these differences manifest themselves in a particular language is a very interesting question, although I think it is far too broad for this site.

Comment: The differences in sg. past tense (-л vs. -ла) refer only to the gender of the subject, but have nothing to do with the sex of the speaker: карандаш упал - книга упала. I'm sure there are no differences between male and female speech in Russian.

Comment: The difference is in 1st p.sg.which is я-pronoun (я сделал, я решил, я сказал, я обдумал) and is therefore related to the concept of Self.

Comment: @ Dima this is not a question about conversational rituals between men and women. It is about monologue speech. I'll make some amendmets.

Comment: This is more about Russian culture than about Russian language, isn't it?

Comment: This is about usage of Russian, socioliguistics and linguopsychology.

Comment: I think this question is valid in the context of this forum.  The forum is called *Russian Language and **Usage*** and this question is specifically about language usage.

Comment: @AleksG The only problem is that **this is not a forum, it's a Q&A site** and the question is quite broad. **Manjusri**, I'll be leaving this open for now, but if it degenerates, it'll most likely be closed. In order to be sure to avoid thar, you could narrow it to specific situations or something more narrow than the whole language.

Comment: @Alenanno What do you mean by 'it degenerates' and what's wrong with collecting  many ideas on the same subject?

Comment: @Manjusri By degenerate I meant getting too many answers basically. :P The problem is not by collecting ideas per se, of course, but rather the fact that SE sites focus on solving specific or reasonably narrow questions. If you ask something that could be a whole book, then it's not a good fit and it usually gets closed. Nothing personal against you, of course.

Comment: 1st. p. sg. past tense and 3rd. p. sg. past tense - я пришла - весна пришла - follow the same pattern, the verb agrees in the grammatical gender, not in sex, there's no category of sex in Russian. Also, there's agreement of the predicative in gender - я умна - я умён. But I insist it gender agreement and it's not differences of male and female speech.

Comment: @shabunc Wait, this is a nearly four-year-old question you've put on hold today? Frankly this looks like, with nothing to currently rogue-moderate, you're having withdrawal symptoms.

Comment: @NikolayErshov this particular question came to my attention because of recent activity. So this is literally the other way around - I don't scan questions all the time desperately seeking for something I can close. All further discussion on this issue will be deleted as something that does not relate to this particular question.

Comment: I have seen the word "секас" for sex only in female posts in the Internet. Also, the phrase "всё пучком".

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, as a native speaker I can assure you that absolutely no grammatic difference between male and female speech exists apart from the past tense you mentioned.

Culturally speaking, modern Russia is so westernized that any difference between genders erased from speech and you can easily find woman which speaks like a brute or a man who speaks tenderly and with care. Women swear, too, there's no unspoken rule about what obscenities are allowed to only men or only women. So, no difference there, too.

Comment: There may be no rule, but there could be measurable and statistically significant difference in frequency of usage between genders (or no difference, which would be unexpected, but that is what science for). Point is, without research it is just a hypothesis.

Comment: Statistics give nothing. It is all about syntax and predicativeness.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is interesting, but too broad for this forum.  You have already pointed out grammatical differences in the past tense: Я сказал vs. Я сказала.  Beyond that, I am sure there are differences in intonation, vocabulary, and probably many other factors.

I have recently listened to an audio course called [He Said/She Said: Women, Men and Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GKVBXI) by Deborah Tannen.  Naturally, her research mainly involves English speakers.  She points out that women speaking English tend to use rising intonation more often then men, making their statements sound a bit like questions.  She also talks about how men tend to talk to convey information, while women tend to use conversation to maintain relationships.

As I have said, this is all pertaining to the speakers of English, but this might be a starting point for you, if you wish to look for similar research concerning the speakers of Russian.

Comment: Asking this OP to do research, is like waiting for the weather by the sea. Sorry, could not resist. :)

Comment: @theUg, that just doesn't sound right in English. :) Getting back to the point, I am not waiting for anything. I cannot answer the question, but I can point the OP to where the answer may be found. The rest is up to the OP. :)

Answer (score -1):

What about Я рад if a man says it, but if a woman says it, it's Я рада. In English, there's no spelling or pronouncing differences but this is what I was wondering about.

Comment: OP writes "The differences in 1st. p. sg. past tense are obvious..." - I think "Я рад/рада" is exactly what he meant.